Using TEXTJOIN to display table values of numbers within a 0.02 range of the highest value
I have this table as shown in Table 1

I want to retrieve the 0-5 table value of the highest 0.xx value in one cell, and also the table values of any other 0.xx value that is within 0.02 of the highest value in a different cell
I can retrieve the highest value using the formula below, and this is shown as "3" in the cell to the right
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15),C14:H14,""))

I can retrieve values that are 0.01 or 0.02 less than this but I have to use different cells for each retrieval. I use the formula below to do this, in this example I use -0.01
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15)-0.01,C14:H14,""))

Is there a way I can combine both of the -0.01 and -0.02 retrievals into a single cell?
There won't always be a value within 0.02 of the highest. There will very unlikely ever be 2 values within that range, but it's fairly common for there to be a single value within 0.02
I have tried to combine the IF command within the formula, but Excel doesn't even try to correct it:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF(OR(C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15)-0.01,C14:H14,""),(C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15)-0.02,C14:H14,"")))


=ARRAYTOTEXT(LET(x, B1:G1, y, B2:G2, FILTER(x, y >= MAX(y) - 0.01)))



Thanks, works a treat after changing the 0.01 to 0.02 (I want values within 0.02 of the max value)

Use FILTER instead of IF and ABS with math.
The FILTER will only return where the value is +/- 0.02 of the max, which will include the max.
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($C$14:$H$14,MAX(C15:H15)-C15:H15<=0.02))



If you only want the those that are not the MAX then we can add to the criteria:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($C$14:$H$14,(MAX(C15:H15)-C15:H15<=0.02)*(MAX(C15:H15)<>C15:H15)))



BTW to fix your IF formula we need to remember that OR does not work in array type formulas and must use + instead.  And that logic should all be in the criteria of a single IF:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,IF((C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15)-0.01)+(C15:H15=MAX(C15:H15)-0.02),C14:H14,""))



May I ask the reason for "Use FILTER instead of IF and ABS with math"? Thank you.

Personal preference.  Filter takes two arguments where IF takes three.  One less thing to fill in.

Thanks Scott, these both display the correct table value I'm after, however I'm now presented with a few more problems.
So if I use the first formula you suggested:
=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,FILTER($C$14:$H$14,MAX(C15:H15)-C15:H15<=0.02))
This works great and shows the results as 3,4
But how can I split those numbers up into their own cells please? I need to then apply other formulas to those numbers.

Ah, easy:
=TEXTSPLIT(I19,",")*1
The *1 turns it into a workable number.
Thanks!!!

Spilling the results, using LET
=LET(
    vals, C15:H15,
    idx, C14:H14,
    include, MAX(vals) - vals <= 0.02,
    TOROW(IF(include, idx, NA()), 2)
)

=LET(
    vals, C15:H15,
    idx, C14:H14,
    d, MAX(vals) - vals,
    include, (d = 0.02) + (d = 0.01),
    TOROW(IF(include, idx, NA()), 2)
)



With LET, spilling the results

Microsoft 365 is required to use TOROW etc. TOROW with parameter 2 is used to ignore NA values
For exactly matching fractions, rounding is needed ROUND(MAX(C15:H15) - C15:H15, 2)

=TOROW(IF(MAX(C15:H15) - C15:H15 <= 0.02, C14:H14, NA()), 2)

=TOROW(IFS(XMATCH(ROUND(MAX(C15:H15) - C15:H15, 2), {0.01,0.02}), C14:H14), 2)



Thanks, little bit complicated for me though!

@user3087904, I prefer using variables with LET, but I've added a non-LET suggestion. Please let me know if any of the steps need clarification.
